# do jquery.jeditable plugin works on mouse click?

Tags: jquery

I am working in MVC & using jquery.jeditable plugin for inplace editing in grid.It is working fine when i make the changes & click on enter button.
But can you please let me know how can i do same editing when i click mouse outside the grid somewhere else on the page.

Please let me know ASAP.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

add onblur: 'submit' to your initialization options.

```
 $('#element').editable('url', {
     onblur    : 'submit'
 });
```